# Разница между конфигурациями Debug и Release в VS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, отладка

Мне известно назначение каждой конфигурации и то, что в Release проводится оптимизация, а в Debug машинный код полностью соответствует написанному программистом. Ну и так же там объявляются разные константы ещё... Меня интересует какая именно отладочная информация содержится в сборке с конфигурацией Debug. По идее генерируется файл PDB и всё. Но ведь и в Release он так же создаётся. В чём разница? Встраивается ли именно в сам модуль какая то отладочная информация? Есть ещё какие то важные отличия между конфигурациями?

Comment: Relise - то же самое что Debug только без отладочных файлов, ресурсов, и других функций. За счёт чего работает быстрее и сборка меньше весит.

Comment: Ну это понятно итак. Ваш ответ не соответствует вопросу...

Comment: `Но ведь и в Release он так же создаётся` Можете в настройках отключить генерирование PDB файлов, если вам они не нужны в релизе.

Comment: При чём тут нужны не нужны. Я про различия спрашиваю

Comment: Вам уже выше ответили про различия. Если вам нужен конкретный, более точный ответ - пишите конкретный, более точный вопрос.

Comment: Конкретных вопросов столько, сколько я поставил знаков вопроса.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debug и Release - это просто *названия* стандартных конфигураций, создаваемых. Никаких завязок именно на имя конфигурации нет. Можно создать свою с названием, например, QQQ - через Build / Configuration Manager.

Поэтому эти конфигурации отличаются только тем, что выставлено для них по умолчанию в свойствах проекта:

- Для Release включена оптимизация кода на уровне компилятора C#
- Для Debug включена константа DEBUG (проще ставить #if в коде)
- Тип выдачи Debugging Information - Full для Debug, PDB Only для Release.

[Режимы Full от PDB Only](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/debug-compiler-option) отличается только тем, что в режиме Full на сборку навешивается атрибут [`DebuggableAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Этот атрибут прямо при старте приложения отключает некоторые оптимизации JIT, и заставляет JIT отслеживать соответствие смещения IL смещению в получаемом нативном коде, что позволяет отладчику более точно отслеживать текущую выполняемую строку.

И настройку оптимизации, и настройку трекинга отладчик может поменять в момент аттача к процессу, DebuggableAttribute просто позволяет сделать это заранее, так что даже методы, обработанные JIT до аттача, будут в неоптимизированном и удобном для отладки варианте.